# Why don't my Perl regexes correctly extract a filename from a path?

Tags: perl

I am trying to parse the filename from paths. I have this:

```
my $filepath = "/Users/Eric/Documents/foldername/filename.pdf";
$filepath =~ m/^.*\\(.*[.].*)$/;
print "Linux path:";
print $1 . "\n\n";
print "-------\n";

my $filepath = "c:\\Windows\eric\filename.pdf";
$filepath =~ m/^.*\\(.*[.].*)$/;
print "Windows path:";
print $1 . "\n\n";
print "-------\n";

my $filepath = "filename.pdf";
$filepath =~ m/^.*\\(.*[.].*)$/;
print "Without path:";
print $1 . "\n\n";
print "-------\n";
```

But that returns:

```
Linux path:

-------
Windows path:Windowsic
                      ilename.pdf

-------
Without path:Windowsic
                      ilename.pdf

-------
```

I am expecting this:

```
Linux path:
filename.pdf
-------
Windows path:
filename.pdf
-------
Without path:
filename.pdf
-------
```

Can somebody please point out what I am doing wrong?

Thanks! :)

Comment: One of the tricks in debugging is to print the data you are working with before you do anything to it. You want to verify that you are starting with what you think you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the answer to what is happening would be: various errors.

```
my $filepath = "/Users/Eric/Documents/foldername/filename.pdf";
$filepath =~ m/^.*\\(.*[.].*)$/;
print "Linux path:";
print $1 . "\n\n";
print "-------\n";
```

`$filepath` doesn't have any `\\`s in it, so it won't match and there's no `$1`. You put `/`s in it. Your expression would have to be:

```
# regular expression matches return their captures in a list context.
my ( $path ) = $filepath =~ m|/([^/.]*\.[^/.]*)$|;
print "Linux path:$path\n\n-------\n"; # little need to . a " string

my $filepath = "c:\\Windows\eric\filename.pdf";
$filepath =~ m/^.*\\(.*[.].*)$/;
print "Windows path:";
print $1 . "\n\n";
print "-------\n";
```

You're using double quotes, which, taking their cue from UNIX shells, are more active than single quote strings. Thus, you need to escape *all* your backslashes, like this:

```
my $filepath = "c:\\Windows\\eric\\filename.pdf";
```

or just use single quotes:

```
my $filepath = 'c:\Windows\eric\filename.pdf';
```

Actually, since perl understands `'/'` for windows, this works too (but not for the regex.)

```
my $filepath = "c:/Windows/eric/filename.pdf";
```

As long as you fix it before handing it back to Windows.

```
my $filepath = "filename.pdf";
$filepath =~ m/^.*\\(.*[.].*)$/;
print "Without path:";
print $1 . "\n\n";
print "-------\n";
```

This didn't *match*, so `$1` is still the last match. That's why it's repeated. But this points up the value of catching the captures instead of referring to `$1`.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out all the errors. This is what I was looking for. :)

Comment: Axeman, can you look at the next entry? The $name at the end doesn't print. That is the last problem to solve on this. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 7):

In this case, as others have said, the mistake is to do it by hand.

In addition to [`File::Basename`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/File-Basename/), you should take a look at [`File::Spec`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/File-Spec/) and [`Path::Class`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Path-Class/). They offer well-tested, cross-platform methods for handling files and directories. [`Path::Class`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Path-Class/) in particular provides helper methods for dealing with file and directory names that are foreign to the system the script lives on. It looks like that might come in handy here.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Path::Class qw/file foreign_file/;

my $nix = "/Users/Eric/Documents/foldername/filename.pdf";
my $win = 'c:\\Windows\eric\filename.pdf'; # single quote to avoid escape issues

print file($nix)->basename(), "\n";
print foreign_file('Win32', $win)->basename(), "\n";
```

Answer (score 4):

Why not use [File::Basename](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Basename.html)?

```
$name = basename($filepath)
print $name
```

---

The regex

```
m/^.*\\(.*[.].*)$/
#    ^^
```

assumes a separator `\`, so case 1 and 3 will never match. In case 2,

```
"c:\\Windows\eric\filename.pdf";
```

`\e` and `\f` are both special characters in Perl. So the code "correctly" returns `Windows\eric\filename.pdf` as the filename. Remember to use `\\`!

Comment: Thank you Kenny for this. I will look into File::Basename but want to get this to work first. :)

Comment: Why waste time getting it to work? Just use what works now and move on in life.

Answer (score 3):

Perl provides this capability:
http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Basename.html

You also need to be wary of string escapes - your Windows path string is being escaped on '\', '\f' and '\e' - it's been a while since I've dealt with Perl escapes, but I'm guessing the \e is also swallowing the 'r' after it. This explains the unexpected output.

Comment: Thank you for this. Sure enough, the \f and \e were problems.