# Create a directory if it does not exist and then create the files in that directory as well

Tags: java, java-io

The condition is if the directory exists it has to create files in that specific directory without creating a new directory.

The below code only creates a file with the new directory but not for the existing directory . For example the directory name would be like "GETDIRECTION":

```java
String PATH = "/remote/dir/server/";
    
String fileName = PATH.append(id).concat(getTimeStamp()).append(".txt");  
             
String directoryName = PATH.append(this.getClassName());   
              
File file  = new File(String.valueOf(fileName));

File directory = new File(String.valueOf(directoryName));

if (!directory.exists()) {
        directory.mkdir();
        if (!file.exists() && !checkEnoughDiskSpace()) {
            file.getParentFile().mkdir();
            file.createNewFile();
        }
}
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
bw.write(value);
bw.close();
```

Answer (score 237, accepted):

This code checks for the existence of the directory first and creates it if not, and creates the file afterwards. Please note that I couldn't verify some of your method calls as I don't have your complete code, so I'm assuming the calls to things like `getTimeStamp()` and `getClassName()` will work. You should also do something with the possible `IOException` that can be thrown when using any of the `java.io.*` classes - either your function that writes the files should throw this exception (and it be handled elsewhere), or you should do it in the method directly. Also, I assumed that `id` is of type `String` - I don't know as your code doesn't explicitly define it. If it is something else like an `int`, you should probably cast it to a `String` before using it in the fileName as I have done here.

Also, I replaced your `append` calls with `concat` or `+` as I saw appropriate.

```
public void writeFile(String value){
    String PATH = "/remote/dir/server/";
    String directoryName = PATH.concat(this.getClassName());
    String fileName = id + getTimeStamp() + ".txt";

    File directory = new File(directoryName);
    if (! directory.exists()){
        directory.mkdir();
        // If you require it to make the entire directory path including parents,
        // use directory.mkdirs(); here instead.
    }

    File file = new File(directoryName + "/" + fileName);
    try{
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        bw.write(value);
        bw.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(-1);
    }
}
```

You should probably not use bare path names like this if you want to run the code on Microsoft Windows - I'm not sure what it will do with the `/` in the filenames. For full portability, you should probably use something like [File.separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971964/file-separator-or-file-pathseparator) to construct your paths.

*Edit*: According to a comment by [JosefScript](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5999589/josefscript) below, it's not necessary to test for directory existence. The `directory.mkdir()`  call will return `true` if it created a directory, and `false` if it didn't, including the case when the directory already existed.

Comment: the calls are working fine. WHen i tried above piece of coed it is still writing the file to PATH but not to the directory . I have used the File.seperator for the new File creation.

Comment: Please explain exactly (with classnames and sample variables) what output you are expecting. I've attached my example program in full here http://pastebin.com/3eEg6jQv so you can see that it does what you are describing (as best as I understand).

Comment: File file = new File(directoryName + "/" + fileName);

i replaced the code snippet above with 
StringBuffer fullFilePath = new StringBuffer(directoryName).append(File.separator).append(fileName);

            File file  = new File(String.valueOf(fullFilePath));

and it worked

Comment: In that case you can use the [`mkdirs()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdirs%28%29) method.

Comment: Why do you have to check for the directory's existence? I played around with this and as far as I can see it does not seem to make a difference, if I create the same directory twice. Even contained files won't get overwritten. Am I missing something?

Comment: No, you're probably not. The problem as asked was to 'create a directory if it doesn't exist', so my code is reflecting that logic, but the JVM's implementation of that call probably won't destroy data if you tell it to create a directory that already exists, so you can call it without the check. If the directory is actually created, the call will return `true`, otherwise `false`. I'll add a note to that effect, thank you.

Comment: As far as I know, Java (at least Java 8) is now happy with forward slashes are directory separators in both Windows and (obviously) Linux.

Answer (score 309):

Java 8+ version:

```
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.Files;

Files.createDirectories(Paths.get("/Your/Path/Here"));
```

The `Files.createDirectories()` creates a new directory and parent directories that do not exist. This method does not throw an exception if the directory already exists.

Comment: What happens if permission is required to create ?

Comment: For Android It only works on API 26 and up so Make sure to check this line  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) https://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/file/Files#createDirectories(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute%3C?%3E...)

Comment: @AjayTakur If you don't have write permission in the directory you're trying to create the new directory in, it throws an IOException

Comment: How can make a process get the permission to create directory on Windows 10?

Comment: What's the performance of this like - can I use it before every file write?

Comment: But it throws an `FileAlreadyExistsException` if the path also includes a filename (ends with a filename).

Comment: Please add the import  for both    Files and for Paths

Answer (score 35):

Trying to make this as short and simple as possible. Creates directory if it doesn't exist, and then returns the desired file:

```
/** Creates parent directories if necessary. Then returns file */
private static File fileWithDirectoryAssurance(String directory, String filename) {
    File dir = new File(directory);
    if (!dir.exists()) dir.mkdirs();
    return new File(directory + "/" + filename);
}
```

Comment: Prefer using File.separatorChar instead of "/".

Answer (score 29):

I would suggest the following for Java8+.

```
/**
 * Creates a File if the file does not exist, or returns a
 * reference to the File if it already exists.
 */
public File createOrRetrieve(final String target) throws IOException {
  final File answer;
  Path path = Paths.get(target);
  Path parent = path.getParent();
  if(parent != null && Files.notExists(parent)) {
    Files.createDirectories(path);
  }
  if(Files.notExists(path)) {
    LOG.info("Target file \"" + target + "\" will be created.");
    answer = Files.createFile(path).toFile();
  } else {
    LOG.info("Target file \"" + target + "\" will be retrieved.");
    answer = path.toFile();
  }
  return answer;
}
```

Edit: Updated to fix bug as indicated by @Cataclysm and @Marcono1234. Thx guys:)

Comment: `Files.createFile(Files.createDirectories(path)).toFile()` should be `Files.createDirectories(path).toFile()` for `Access Denied` reason.

Comment: @Pytry, `Files.createFile(Files.createDirectories(path))` does not work as described in the comment above. `createDirectories` already creates a directory with the file name, e.g. "test.txt", therefore `createFile` will fail.

Answer (score 11):

### Simple Solution using using `java.nio.Path`

```
public static Path createFileWithDir(String directory, String filename) {
        File dir = new File(directory);
        if (!dir.exists()) dir.mkdirs();
        return Paths.get(directory + File.separatorChar + filename);
    }
```

Answer (score 9):

**code:**

```
// Create Directory if not exist then Copy a file.


public static void copyFile_Directory(String origin, String destDir, String destination) throws IOException {

    Path FROM = Paths.get(origin);
    Path TO = Paths.get(destination);
    File directory = new File(String.valueOf(destDir));

    if (!directory.exists()) {
        directory.mkdir();
    }
        //overwrite the destination file if it exists, and copy
        // the file attributes, including the rwx permissions
     CopyOption[] options = new CopyOption[]{
                StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING,
                StandardCopyOption.COPY_ATTRIBUTES

        };
        Files.copy(FROM, TO, options);


}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you create a web based application, the better solution is to check the directory exists or not then create the file if not exist. If exists, recreate again.

```
    private File createFile(String path, String fileName) throws IOException {
       ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
       File file = new File(classLoader.getResource(".").getFile() + path + fileName);

       // Lets create the directory
       try {
          file.getParentFile().mkdir();
       } catch (Exception err){
           System.out.println("ERROR (Directory Create)" + err.getMessage());
       }

       // Lets create the file if we have credential
       try {
           file.createNewFile();
       } catch (Exception err){
           System.out.println("ERROR (File Create)" + err.getMessage());
       }
       return  file;
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution using Java 8

```
public void init(String multipartLocation) throws IOException {
    File storageDirectory = new File(multipartLocation);

    if (!storageDirectory.exists()) {
        if (!storageDirectory.mkdir()) {
            throw new IOException("Error creating directory.");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Java 8 or above, then `Files.createDirectories()` method works the best.