# FileNotFoundException while trying to open a File

Tags: java, file

I am trying to d `file = new file (location)` while location of file is absolute path with somethign like this : `\\test\hold\REPO/TEST/Letter/123.pdf`
I am getting file not found exception while files are there in this path. what could be going wrong? can i have path with both forward and backward slash?

Comment: Try to list all the files in the path using list method of File class to check whether file is actually present in the path or not ? If file exists then see the case of file name, even extension ? Problem is either the program is not taking the correct path or there is a mismatch between file name and what you have given in code.

Comment: Why are slashes different?

Comment: Please look into : `File.separator` variable. This answer might help you too : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971964/file-separator-or-file-pathseparator

Answer (score 0):

String separator = System.getProperty("file.separator");
So location can be rewritten to
location=separator+"test"+separator+"hold"+separator +"REPO"+separator "TEST"+separator+"Letter"+separator+"123.pdf";
In this case no need to think about underlying OS

Answer (score 0):

You need two slashes in a string literal to represent one in the filename. Try

```
"\\\\test\\hold\\REPO/TEST/Letter/123.pdf"
```

or better still

```
"//test/hold/REPO/TEST/Letter/123.pdf"
```

There is never a need to use a backslash in a filename in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding quotes around the filename.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your code without single backward slashes.if you want to use back-word slashes use \\ instead of  \ .A single backward slashes create a problem if you put it inside the String literal.So you can write you code in multiple ways to avoid your exceptions.

```
1)  File f=new File("\\test/hold/REPO/TEST/Letter/123.pdf");
2)  File f=new File("\\test\\hold\\REPO/TEST/Letter/123.pdf");
3)  File f=new File("\\test\\hold\\REPO\\TEST\\Letter\\123.pdf");
4)  File f=new File("/test/hold/REPO/TEST/Letter/123.pdf");
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use :-
`InputStream input = new URL("\\test\hold\REPO/TEST/Letter/123.pdf").openStream();`
or

```
File file = new File(location);
```

where `location=\\test\hold\REPO/TEST/Letter/123.pdf;` and Check Using SOP statement whether URL is Call properly or not . hope it will help you to fine better solution