# JavaCompiler classpath Windows vs Linux

Tags: java, classpath, java-compiler-api

I want to make a tool that can generate and compile java source code and generate a jar file from it:

For this i use the JavaCompiler:

```
JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
```

When i add the classpath to the Java SystemCompiler:

```
optionList.addAll(Arrays.asList("-cp", classpath));
```

it works for Windows when i setup my classpath with ";" as seperator:

```
classpath = "jar1.jar;jar2.jar;dir/jar3.jar;dir/jar4.jar";
```

In Linux it fails.

When i use space instead of ; like:

```
classpath = "jar1.jar jar2.jar lib/jar3.jar lib/jar4.jar";
```

it fails for both systems.

Same goes for:

```
classpath = "lib/*"
```

I would need a solution that can generate a working classpath system independently.

**UPDATE (Solution):**

Ok i found out that there is a java offers

```
File.pathseparator
```

Which changes corresponding to the System Environment.

See also [File.separator or File.pathSeparator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971964/file-separator-or-file-pathseparator)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On linux you should use `:`

> CLASSPATH = path1:path2:...

Oracle documentation:

[Linux](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/classpath.html)

[Windows](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html)

Answer (score 1):

Use `:` on linux instead of `;` that you are regular to use on windows.

Comment: Is there a possibility that i can generate a working CP system independently?

Comment: Please clarify your question. Do you mean that you want to create script that runs on any platform and generates classpath following rules of current platform?