# Windows to Ubuntu Java sqlite missing database

Tags: java, windows, sqlite, ubuntu

I am working on a simple program in java, which I use to read and write a few things in one SQLITE database, located within the directory I have the jar file. To access the database and a settings file, I use the

```
String wd = System.getProperty("user.dir");
String dbName = "jdbc:sqlite:"+wd+"\\"+sqliteDataNae;
c = DriverManager.getConnection(dbName);
```

Long story short, 
I have made a jar file wrapping all libraries in and tested it in Windows where everything works fine. I get my data stored in my database. Not exception at all!

Then I transfer all my files in a rar file to an ubuntu (14) hyperv virtual machine. 
I use the terminal to go to my directory where I have unzipped everything, and run:

```
java -jar myJar.jar
```

The script starts running, I get my println and the setting are all loaded (hence no issue reading the settings txt file - located in the same directory as the database = no directory issue), 
The problem is that I get an sqlite exception `[SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such table: User)`.

However, I open my database (using SQLite Database Browser) and the table exists.

Is there any logical explanation for this? and is there any solution?

Comment: Does your code check if opening the database actually succeeds? That is not clear from the snippet you posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is since Linux uses forward slashes for path separators you'll need to replace '\\' with '/'. However to make life easier just use File.separator instead as it automatically gives you the default separator for the current OS.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this was actually what was going on. Unfortunately i thought that due to the fact that it reads the settings file this would not be an issue. However I reach the settings file in another way (using dir)

pathSeparator did not work, however File.separator did :)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971964/file-separator-or-file-pathseparator

(I suppose it might be good to update your answer and if you have understood something differently please let me know so that I could update my question)

Comment: yes you're right, it should be separator not pathSeparator. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `File.pathSeparator` it's used to separate individual file paths (Every OS uses different kind of Path variable).

For windows, it’s `‘\’` and for unix it’s `‘/’`.

e.g: `File file = new File("abc"+File.separator+"def.txt");`

//on Unix system prints: abc/def.txt