# java.io.FileNotFoundException occurs

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am trying to run the below code, but error occurs,The filename I mentioned is present on the given path.

```
    public class DataDriventc {
    public static void main(String []args) throws BiffException,    IOException{
    File f = new File("‪C:/Users/Avnish/Desktop/Input.xlsx");
    Workbook w = Workbook.getWorkbook(f);

    Sheet s = w.getSheet("Sheet1");
    int columns = s.getColumns();
    int rows = s.getRows();
    System.out.println(columns + "," + rows);

    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
File f = new File("‪C:\\Users\\Avnish\\Desktop\\Input.xlsx");
```

For reference, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971964/file-separator-or-file-pathseparator) question.